# Sequence from sub-sequence parts?

Tags: algorithm, graph, sequence

Let say I have the following items :

```
 1;2;3;4;5;[1,2];[3,4];[1,2,3];[2,3,4]
```

(note: i don't have all the permutations available, just part of them)

also  every item has a score associated with it.
Now the task is to build the sequence out of the available parts :

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

There are many ways to create the sequence :

```
the simplest : 1,2,3,4,5
or : [1,2],[3,4], 5
or : 1,[2,3,4], 5
or : [1,2],[3,4],5
or : ........
```

the correct sequence should be the one with the highest score.

How would you do that ?
Graphs?

Comment: How is this a graph and how do you calculate scores?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: see my answer for how this is isomorphic to a graph.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive process to walk through a graph.  Each sub-sequence is a node.  The edges connect nodes where the end integer of the source node is adjacent to the first integer of the destination node.

For instance, you have edges from [1] to [2] and [2, 3, 4].  You also have edges from [1, 2] to [3] and [3, 4].

This reduces the problem to Dijkstra's algorithm, finding the best path through a graph with weighted edges.